# How to calculate the volume of the ship under a surface

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Now I am working on calculating the volume of the ship,the figure of the ship under the water can be described as follows:

```
    0 0 0
    -20 12 0
    -20 18 0
    0 30 0
    0 10 -5
    0 20 -5
    0 30 02
    20 0 0
    20 10 -5
    20 20 -5
    20 30 0
    40 0 0
    40 10 -5
    40 20 -5
    40 30 0
    60 0 0
    60 10 -5
    60 20 -5
    60 30 0
    80 0 0
    80 10 -5
    0 20 -5
    80 30 0
    00 0 0
    100 10 -5
    100 20 -5
    100 30 0
    101 15 0
    100 0 0
```

then

```
    text = load('---.txt')
    x = text(:,1) ;
    y = text(:,2) ;
    z = text(:,3) ;
    tri = delaunay(x,y);
    tmp=trisurf(tri,x,y,z);
```

and i get the approximate shape of the ship ,but how do i calculate the volume of it under z=0 ?

Comment: Consider using [griddata](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html) for interpolation of scattered data then sum grid values.

Comment: Thanks and i get the approximate volume with the linear interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your 3d-object is not really defined until you provide both vertices (which you have) and faces, which are approximated (badly, for this purpose) by the delanuay triangulation.

With the correct triangulation you can call [Volume of a triangulated surface mesh](https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37742-volume-of-a-triangulated-surface-mesh) found at Mathworks file exchange.